# What is the > & <= version of %between%?

Tags: r, data.table

`%between% c(1,2)` is equivalent to `>=1 & <= 2` or `>1 & < 2` if set `incbounds = FALSE`, but what if I want `> 1 & <= 2`? Is there an operator in data.table for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it yourself:

```r
`%rightin%` <- function(x, y) x > y[[1]] & x <= y[[2]]

1 %rightin% c(1, 2)
#[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

You should read about the manual [here](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/between.html)

> between(x, lower, upper, incbounds=TRUE, NAbounds=TRUE, check=FALSE)
>
> x %between% y
>
> inrange(x, lower, upper, incbounds=TRUE)
>
> x %inrange% y

As you can see, there are options regarding if boundaries are inclusive or exclusive. By default, they are inclusive. thus being `>=` and `<=`

Comment: it seems incbounds set left and right bound together, so can't fulfill my goal of including bound only on one side